# Testing app colors are off when deplying through TestFlight

Tags: xcode, testflight, iosdeployment

I am ready to test my app using TestFlight. I have gone through the whole process and have installed the app through the testFlight app in order to test it. When I Open it however, I noticed that the colors are way off which causes some UI elements to not be visible.

I have no idea what could be causing this and therefore have no hints as to how to fix it.

When I run the app into my device from Xcode it looks fine.

Test Flight app:
[image: Test Flight Image]

Xcode run:
[image: Xcode run screenshot]

Comment: Turns out I had not set background or text colors on some elements and so when the background changed colors due to the dark/light theme and the default color being black/white some elements looked invisible

Answer (score 0):

The penny dropped for me, after hours of rebuilding, resubmitting etc.

DARK MODE... , need I say more :(

If so, check if your phone is on Dark or Light Mode, and if you have a theme for both.

It worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).